# valueOf method of String returns 4 when we pass a null string

Tags: java

I just found something interesting.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(null).length());
    }

}
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

This is what I kind of expected.

But when i run this

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        String s=null;
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s).length());
    }

}
```

Output

```
4
```

There are two overloaded version of valueOf which gets called,they are

```
/**
     * Returns the string representation of the <code>Object</code> argument.
     *
     * @param   obj   an <code>Object</code>.
     * @return  if the argument is <code>null</code>, then a string equal to
     *          <code>"null"</code>; otherwise, the value of
     *          <code>obj.toString()</code> is returned.
     * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the string representation of the <code>char</code> array
     * argument. The contents of the character array are copied; subsequent
     * modification of the character array does not affect the newly
     * created string.
     *
     * @param   data   a <code>char</code> array.
     * @return  a newly allocated string representing the same sequence of
     *          characters contained in the character array argument.
     */
    public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
    return new String(data);
    }
```

I didn't get why valueOf(Object s) method is giving special treatment to null.
Thoughts/Comments?

Comment: Because the best suitable method is being found and its being processed. Even though you are setting the String s to null, you have declared a String which is occupying memory. That is why you are getting output as 4.#

Comment: I think the real question here is not why the output is 4 or a NPE is thrown but why both method act differently given null as parameter.

Comment: I kind of agree with Tunaki why this difference when given null as parameter.

Comment: _"I didn't get why valueOf(Object s) method is giving special treatment to null. "_ For `valueOf(Object obj)`, the check is there to avoid you calling a method on a potential `null` reference. If it wasn't there, this method would be completely pointless as it's the same as calling `myObj.toString()`. So it's a utility method (o/w everyone would have it in its code base I guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is from the method invocation logic of JLS.

[JLS's Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) states,

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the **most specific method is chosen**.

Now, in your first case, when you pass `null` directly,

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(null).length());
```

Both `String.valueOf(Object)` and `String.valueOf(char[])` are applicable... So it uses the **most specific method** which is a `char[]`.

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

But in your second case, you are actually passing a `String` even though it's null.

So only `String.valueOf(Object)` is applicable.

Comment: We can help compiler chose *safe* method by explicitly showing which overloaded version we are interested in. We can do it by casting `null` to specific type like `String.valueOf((String)null)` which will invoke `valueOf(Object)`.

Answer (score 2):

From `valueOf` docs

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.